# What is the REST API convention for bulk fetch when it's necessary to include a body?

Tags: rest, naming-conventions

I need to add an API endpoint that is used for fetching multiple records. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
GET /widgets?ids=1,2,3
```

However, in this case, the possible length of the URL will exceed the maximum character count of 2,083 characters.

In order to get around this limitation, I will need to use a POST request with a request body:

```
{
  "ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

But now my endpoint doesn't seem right and I can't think of a good naming convention:

```
POST /widgets
POST /get-widgets
POST /widgets-queries
```

What is the REST convention in this scenario?

Comment: What is the use case? would it make sense to apply pagination or filters instead of listing all ids?

Comment: I would recommend using filters. And that maximum is also a bit outdated.

Otherwise, use a POST to something like /widget-queries, specifying the ids in the body. The POST returns a 303 (see other) to a url containing the results of your request. See https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16583/HTTP-Patterns---Bouncer/25829

Comment: @Mara No, it's an optimization for fetching individual records by ID. There's no "fetch all" endpoint.

Comment: @Michiel Seems like you should post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using filters on the GET endpoint. That maximum is also a bit outdated, most of the browsers nowadays support more than the 2K of characters.

Otherwise, use a POST to something like `/widget-queries`, specifying the ids in the body.

The POST returns a `303 (see other)` to a URL containing the results of your request. See gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16583/HTTP-Patterns---Bouncer/

This makes the request also cacheable.